# dynamic svg text doesn't show on screen

Tags: javascript, svg

I know there were several similar questions asked already, sadly none solved my problem. I'm adding a text svg element to a g container, the sourcecod shows its added properly, but the text doesnt show up.

```
var mess = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','g');
  mess.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(100, 0)');
  mess.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'message');
var svgbox = document.querySelector('.islandBox');
  svgbox.append(mess);

var bg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
  bg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '1500');
  bg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '450');
  bg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', '/assets/images/messagebg.svg');
var profile = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
  profile.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '300');
  profile.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '450');
  profile.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', '/assets/images/profile'+ profileImgId +'.svg');
var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.ord/2000/svg','text');
  text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '100');
  text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '100');
  text.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'font: italic 80px serif; fill: black');
  var t = document.createTextNode(textContent);
  text.appendChild(t);
svgbox = document.querySelector('#message');
  svgbox.append(bg);
  svgbox.append(profile);
  svgbox.append(text);
```

Background and profile pic work properly, just the text isn't shown, is there any trivial error i oversaw? Result in chrome:

```
<svg class="islandBox" id="islandBox" viewBox="0, 0, 2000, 1200">
<g transform="translate(100, 0)" id="message">
<image width="1500" height="450" xlink:href="/assets/images/messagebg.svg"></image>
<image width="300" height="450"xlink:href="/assets/images/profile0.svg"></image>
<text x="0" y="100" style="font: italic 80px serif; fill: black">introduction text</text></g></svg>
```

changing the position of the text element didn't have any results, so the text shouldn't be offscreen.

Help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not behind the images, chrome also doesnt show me any area allocated for the element as it does with the images or g element. Without the images i just get an empty g.

Comment: thats weird, it doesn't do it in chrome with my page O_o

Comment: removed the class, only has the id and your suggested attributs, but still doesn't work. Its weird.

Comment: `http://www.w3.ord/2000/svg` is a typo, you need org there like the other createElementNS.

Comment: ah, great, thank you, i knew it would be something so stupid,but it completely evaded me >_<